# Structures - System.Runtime.Interoptservice C++ vs. C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, struct

I got a struct in C++ and want to use this in C#. Since months, this is functioning perfectly. Now, I changed the structs a little bit, and nothing is functioning any more:

Attached the struct defined in C++:

```
typedef struct TCell{
    struct TPoint P;
    struct TFace** ppFace;
    struct TNode** ppNode;

   double Volume;
   unsigned int nFace;
   unsigned int nNode;
   unsigned long Index;
   unsigned long Index2;

   struct TFamily* pFamily;
}TCell;
```

Attached the struct in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TCell
{
    public TPoint P;
    public TFace** ppFace;
    public TNode** ppNode;

    public double Volume;
    public UInt16 nFace;
    public UInt16 nNode;
    public UInt32 Index;
    public UInt32 Index2;

    public TFamily* pFamily;
}
```

Commenting the variables `nNode` and `ppNode`, everything is functioning great. Uncommenting this variables, C# is showing the value of `Index` when asking for `nNode`.

In C++ the output is correct.

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2015.

`sizeof(TCell)` returns `72` in both C# and C++

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is `int` 16 bits in C++ (on your platform)? Is `long` 32 bits? You might want to use `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` just to make sure the sizes match the C#.

Comment: @immibis people never learn to use those typedefs. And they ask why they exists. Your comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You have `unsigned int` in C++, but `UInt16` in C#. You probably meant to use `UInt32`.

Comment: Hallo. I copied the code, so there are no misstakes. I also made a table to compare the size:

Comment: In C#: sizeof(TPoint) = 24; sizeof(TFace**) = 8; sizeof(TNode**) = 8; sizeof(double) = 8; sizeof(UInt16) = 2; sizeof(UInt32) = 4; sizeof(TFamily*) = 8

Comment: As far as i know, unsigned int == UInt16 and unsigned long == UInt32 - at my plattform Windows7/64 Bit

Comment: Nope, both `int` and `long` are 32-bit.

Comment: @CJens Use typedefs such as uint32_t. An advice. It will automatically determine the size of the type for underlying system.

Comment: But, commenting only nNode and ppNode, its running. There are still UInt16 and UInt32 variables contained.

Comment: And the size of the struct is the same in C++ and C#

Answer (score 0):

In C++, `nFace` and `nNode` are `unsigned int`s (which, on Windows, are 32 bits long). In C#, they're `UInt16`s. These do not match!

You should use `uint16_t` in your C++ code (and `uint32_t` for the 32-bit ones) to make sure the types match.

It's bad practice to rely on `int` or `long` being 32 bits, since it will come back to bite you if you ever want to port your program to a platform where they aren't - e.g. `long` is 64 bits on 64-bit Linux.

Comment: I'll try thank you. But how could it function with only one UInt16 and UInt32 variable and why is the size of the whole struct the same?

Comment: @CJens At a guess, C# adds 16 bits of padding between `nFace` and `Index`, which happen to line up with the second half of `nFace` in C++.